# Autodesk Forge Model Derivative API - type and istance parameters

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I want to know, in a revit model on BIM360, if is possibile to distinguish type parameters from istance parameters with model derivative API (data extraction).
Is it possible?

TIA
Alder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe, in the model derivative API, you can check whether the parameter value is associated with an element type or an instance object. If that check does not answer the question conclusively, you could use the Design Automation API to check for sure.