# Shared parameters vs built-in parameters in model derivative API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I'm looking for some clarification on the Type vs. Instance hierarchy in Model Derivative API responses, specifically with Revit parameters in the `properties` object.

I have a Doors category with a mix of properties that are both Built-in Type Parameters and Shared Family Parameters (see screenshots below). In Revit when editing the type for the door, we can see both of these parameters and their values.

But when when getting the model properties via the [Model Derivative API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/metadata/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/) (after the model as been translated), it appears that only the built-in type parameters are available on each Door instance. Type Mark and Door Type (both built-in parameters) show on the instance, but Frame Type (a shared family parameters) does not.

Is this expected behavior? If so, do you have any suggestions on how to get the shared parameter value for a particular instance? I may look into [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68683577/autodesk-forge-model-derivative-api-type-and-istance-parameters) but this seemed like an inconsistency with the properties.

```
[
    // Instance
  {
    "objectid": 52,
    "name": "DOOR_DD4_F2",
    "externalId": "8a6cf411-ac2f-4379-9b63-7360f7473e2f-0005bf68",
    "properties": {
      "Identity Data": {
        "Type Name": "1830 x 2135 mm, 44 mm Thickness",
        "Mark": "1",
        "Type Mark": "12"

        /* ... */
      },
      "Construction": {
        "Door Type": "DD4"
        /* ... */
      }
    }
  },

    // Type
  {
    "objectid": 3368,
    "name": "1830 x 2135 mm, 44 mm Thickness",
    "externalId": "8a6cf411-ac2f-4379-9b63-7360f7473e2f-0005bf0b",
    "properties": {
      "Identity Data": {
        "Type Mark": "12"
      },

      "Construction": {
        /* Frame type is here, but not in the instance. Not sure why. */
        "Frame Type": "F2",
        "Door Type": "DD4"
      },
    }
  }
]
```

**Built-In Parameters**

[image: built-in parameters screenshot]
[image: shared parameters screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a Revit model with one family. One parameter of the type of the family is a shared parameter. After translating, it looks the data is available. Could you please provide sample model + family for us to diagnose?

[image]

Comment: please send test files to aps.help @autodesk.com if you do not want to share in public

Comment: Hi Xiaodong - thanks for looking into this. In your example where does the `xiaodong-family` element exist in the model hierarchy? We do see the shared parameters on type elements, but not a level lower underneath instance elements.

If my question isn't clear, I'll look into sending this model over via email.

Comment: Hi Alex, I was on a long holiday. My test case is simplest. I created this shared param in one family and inserted the family to one revit model. Could you share a demo model and family ? We will check how to reproduce it. thanks